# Photoshop Script to change Font and Font Size

Tags: javascript, automation, action, photoshop

Looking for a script that changes all text within a PSD to be a certain font size and font kind, in this particular case, 'AbrilFatface-Regular'@ 101px. I then want to use this script to batch change hundreds of files using the same font and size (so no need for a prompt).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works like a champ:

```
if(app.documents.length != 0){
var doc = app.activeDocument;

for(i = 0; i < doc.artLayers.length; ++i){
    var layer = doc.artLayers[i];

    if(layer.kind == LayerKind.TEXT){
        layer.textItem.font = "REPLACE WITH POSTSCRIPT FONT NAME";
        layer.textItem.size = new UnitValue(REPLACE WITH FONT SIZE,  "px");
    }
}
}
```